# Why UIWebView's loading can not work correctly?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Before stoping uiwebview, we usually check if its loading is YES or NO like this

```
if(self.webView.loading){
    [self.webView stopLoading];
}
```

But I found that isLoading will return NO even it is loading. So it does not work correctly.

Therefore I just call stopLoading directly. Why is this happened ? Or any wrong workaround I have ?

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
if([self.webView isLoading]){
    [self.webView stopLoading];
}
```

I think you just miss the "message object brackets" around "self.webView isLoading"

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to a bug in iOS 5 and it's fixed in iOS6.

> FIXED: In iOS 6, a bug was fixed where UIWebView.isLoading was set to NO before the main frame finished loading. Now, UIWebView.isLoading is set to NO when the main frame is done loading.

Source: http://www.bgr.com/2012/07/16/ios-6-download-beta-3-change-log/